# update profile php

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, insert-into

I have create a profile page in php. The page includes the address and telephone fields and prompts the users to insert their data. Data are then saved in my table named profile.
Everything works fine, but the problem is that the table updated only if it includes already data. How can I modify it (probably mysql query that I have in my function), so that data will be entered into the table even if it is empty. Is there a something like UPDATE OR INSERT INTO syntax that I can use?
Thanks

```
<?php


if ( isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success'])===true ){
echo'profile updated sucessfuly';
}else{

 if( empty($_POST) === false  &&  empty($errors) === true ){

    $update_data_profile = array(
                'address' => $_POST['address'],
                'telephone' => $_POST['telephone'],
                );


   update_user_profile($session_user_id, $update_data_profile);

   header('Location: profile_update.php?success');

   exit();


}else if ( empty($errors) === false ){
   echo output_errors($errors);
}

?>
```

and then by using the following function

```
function update_user_profile($user_id, $update_data_profile){

$update = array();

array_walk($update_data_profile, 'array_sanitize');

foreach($update_data_profile as $field => $data )
    {              
        $update[]='`' . $field . '` = \'' . $data . '\'';
}


     mysql_query(" UPDATE `profile` SET " . implode(',  ', $update) . " WHERE `user_id` = $user_id ") or die(mysql_error());


}
```

Comment: How does your array_sanitize method behave when ur input is empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to the posted answer by psu, and will definatly check into that, but from a quick readthrough, you need to be very careful when using those special syntaxes.

1 reason that comes to mind: you have no knowledge of what might be happening to the table that you're inserting to or updating info from. If multiple uniques are defined, then you might be in serious trouble, and this is a common thing when scaling applications.

2 the replace into syntax is a functionality i rarely wish to happen in my applications. Since i do not want to loose data from colomns in a row that was allready in the table.

i'm not saying his answer is wrong, just stating precaution is needed when using it because of above stated reasons and possible more.

as stated in the first article, i might be a newbie for doing this but at this very moment i prefer:

```
$result = mysql_query("select user_id from profile where user_id = $user_id limit 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) === 1){
    //do update like you did
}
else{
    /** 
     *  this next line is added after my comment, 
     *  you can now also leave the if(count()) part out, since the array will now alwayss
     *  hold data and the query won't get invalid because of an empty array
     **/
    $update_data_profile['user_id'] = $user_id;
    if(count($update_data_profile)){
        $columns = array();
        $values = array();
        foreach($update_data_profile as $field => $data){
            $columns[] = $field;
            $values[] = $data;
        }
        $sql = "insert into profile (" .  implode(",", $columns) .") values ('" . implode("','", $values) . "')" ;
        var_dump($sql); //remove this line, this was only to show what the code was doing
        /**update**/
        mysql_query($sql) or echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed the function using the above code. The problem is that the table once again can be updated, but no data insert in table when it is empty. I forgot to mention before that I use 2 tables. The 1st table called users and includes the user_id. The other table called profile and includes (profile_id, address, telephone, user_id). In profile table the user_id is the Foreign Key.  For the foreign key i did the following set:  Internal relation :users.user_id  Foreign key constraint `users`.`user_id`  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT.

Comment: why would you want to insert a completly empty row into a database? this is the same as no row would be there? I guess i didn't notice that part in your question :p, i'll update the answer, but i really don't get why one would do this

Comment: Ok I will explain. I have 2 tables in my database. Table USERS holds the user_id and some other info needed during the users' registration. Table PROFILE holds info about users' profile. user_id is a foreign key to profile table. So I made a form that prompts user to create his profile. This form will collect all info about users' profile and will store them in table profile in database. In case that user has not created his profile, profile table will be empty(so...INSERT INTO). If user has already created his profile, he will be able using the same form to update his profile (so...UPDATE).

Comment: Yes, i figured that much, but why insert an empty record in the database? if a user submits an empty form, that's just not worth submitting to the database: if data is empty, that you shouldn't have a row in the profile table, it's not because you have FK's that you always need to set up the relation, only if the relation exists. thus if a user has a profile, you set up the relation by inserting the row, if the user didn't fill in the form, then you don't insert to row. Anyway, if my answer helped you, can you pls accept. Thx

Comment: by the way... I would like to ask you something final. Everything seems to work fine, no errors at all, but the problem is that when I get in phpmyadmin the table profile gets no data in it if it is empty. Data get into table only on update when I already have data in it. I get no error messages so I cannot find out why this might happen. Any idea ? Thnx

Comment: i'm not to sure that i'm getting what you're asking, so apologies if my reply is off mark. But, if you only copy pasted my code, then the actual line that's sending query to database is missing and you should replace var_dump($sql) with mysql_query($sql). var_dump($sql) was only to show you what the code above was doing. if this comment didn't help you, perhaps you should post another question. you can also try "mysql_query($sql) or echo mysql_error()" to see if the query has any errors. see update in answer

Comment: Once again thanks for your help! I followed your orders. By using the "or echo mysql_error()", i get the error messages on screen. The only error that I get is this: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DATABASE`.`profile`, CONSTRAINT `profile_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION).

Comment: Dear Bobybag thanks for your last response. Thanks to you it works. The only thing missing was to insert 'user_id' => $session_user_id in the $update_data_profile array. Once again thanks...you are a genius.

Comment: A last question to this will be the following. The above code that we have used updates all the fields in table each time we do the update. How could it be modified so that it will update only certain fields. For example if the user inserts in form only his telephone number, then only the telephone field in table to be upadated and keep the other fields as they are.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the table if there isn't any data in it corresponding the user_id, meaning that you must have a row containing the user_id and null or something else for the other fields.

a) You can try to check if the table contains data and if not insert it else use update (not ideal)

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ...");       
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 0)    
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT ...");
```

b) Checkout this links

http://www.kavoir.com/2009/05/mysql-insert-if-doesnt-exist-otherwise-update-the-existing-row.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

@Stefanos

you can use use "REPLACE INTO " command in place of  "INSERT INTO" in the SQL query.

for example

Suppose you have insert query

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME,ADD) values ('ABC','XYZZ');
```

Now you can use following query as combination of insert and update

```
REPLACE INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME,ADD) values ('ABC','XYZZ');
```

Hope this will help!